# Magento 2.3.2 - Unable to get Currency Rates for INR to USD form Store => Currency => Currency Rates

Tags: magento2, currency, multicurrency, currency-rates

I am currently using `Magento version 2.3.2`.

I want to show currency switcher for `INR` and `USD` and want to show `INR` as default currency on the front-end, for this, I have made some setting in the **Store => configuration => General => Currency Setup**.

Please find the attached snapshot of the setting below:

[image]

[image]

As per the above setting when I want to get currency rate I am getting error

> Notice: Undefined index: INR_USD in /var/www/html/magento232/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency/Import/CurrencyConverterApi.php on line 91

Please find the snapshot of error page below:

[image]

Please suggest how can I configure currency switcher.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known issue and you can check at  [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21487)

It also got Fixed [Here](https://github.com/Jitheesh/magento2/commit/fa1d2d2e2a20ae72162575e26976f12dd437e188)

Now `Currency Converter API` need an API to work.

You can get API from https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/

This issue has been fixed in Magento version 2.3.3

You can download Magento 2.3.3 and replace following file

> vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency/Import/CurrencyConverterApi.php
>
> vendor/magento/module-directory/etc/adminhtml/system.xml
>
> vendor/magento/module-directory/etc/config.xml

Or You can also upgrade to Magento 2.3.3

Hope above will help!

Comment: Hi @pawan, Thanks to you for solving my problem, your suggestion really works for me.

Comment: @Aatif, welcome and glad to know. You can accept answer if it worked for you :)